# Normal matrix over $\mathbb C$ can be diagonalized to an invertible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Is it true that

> Every normal matrix over  $\mathbb C$  can be diagonalized to an invertible matrix.

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fact (true over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$): if
$$
A = U D U^{-1},
$$
and $D$ is invertible, then $A$ is invertible. (Can you prove this?)

Given this fact, you should be able to answer your question.

Comment: $A$ and $D$ have same determinant so $A$ invertible iff $D$ invertible.

Comment: Not every normal matrix is invertible so we are done!

Comment: @izimath Yes indeed